# Different code “convention” in questions than in comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, code

My first question here.

Displaying backticks is apparently difficult. But it's not, just surround the inline code by more backticks than those that appear (concatenated) in the code. E.g., If you want `` ` `` you need to write ``` `` ` `` ```, and if you want `````` ````` `````` you need ``````` `````` ````` `````` ```````. This is not so clean, but “works”.

Now try that on a comment. Does it work?

It seems that in a comment you need to use the *usual*  markdown convention of escaping backticks, that is, if you want `` ` `` you need ``` `\`` ``` (and the same for ```` ``` ````, you need ``` `\`\`\`` ```.

So… the question is, is there a reason for this? Why not the same on both questions and answers? I see `` ` `` written “bad” all the times, but this behaviour is even more confusing.

Comment: Related sandbox http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208/formatting-sand-box

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the help on Markdown](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help), *StackExchange* has programmed "[[comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to] support only bold, italic, code and links; in addition, a few shorthand links [...]".

Comments, in general, *should* be used only or limited interaction between posters and other contributors. As such, providing the same markdown capabilities has (most likely) been decided as not necessary. Perhaps the same goes for its implementation.

My conclusion is therefore that this is [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design).

Comment: So this means that the question/answer system is a feature?

Comment: @Manuel: Questions/answers (posts) are covered by the full markdown, while comments are covered by a reduced subset of this, plus some SE-specific add-ons. That's all I'm saying.